# defining a non-templated class from a templated class

Tags: c++

Let's say i've got a templated class called model. now let's declare a class within this class called texture, that requires no template arguments. How do i go about defining it so that no matter the template argument given to the Model class, the texture object is the same. This is what it looks like.

```
template<class T>
class Model
{
    class Texture;
};

class Model::Texture //error because model requires a template argument.
{


};
```

so is there anything i can do here?

Comment: If `Texture` isn't really dependent on `Model`, you can move it to outside the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have to write that this way:

```
template<typename T>
class Model<T>::Texture 
{
  //you should be able to use T here, even though Texture is not a template!

   T m_data;   //T here
   Texture(T data); //T here also, as the constructor parameter!

};
```

As `Model` is a class template, so here `T` applies to `Model` only. `Texture` is still a non-template.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/yGARF)

Comment: As far as I understand things, this would still mean that `Model<int>::Texture` is a different class than `Model<double>::Texture`. They won't assign to one another, and the compiler will likely duplicate all code for them.

Comment: oh, this actually still works for my purposes. i understand that they will be technically different classes, i just couldn't figure how to define the non-template class inside without errors. It does work fine now. Will accept answer when it lets me

Comment: Hey, @Nawaz, in the OP Texture was an inner class of the Model. You have to mention this is some way.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: The phrase "how to do X without errors" is the same as just "how to do X", isn't it?

Comment: One more note: in terms of many compiler aspects, `Texture` *is* a template. One consequence of this is that you cannot simply bundle off its implementation to a separate translation unit. You'll either have to ensure that they will be instantiated for all required template arguments, or make the implementation available in a header so that the compiler can take care of instantiation.

Comment: @MvG: `Texture` *is not* a template here. It *depends* on template argument, which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: Quoting from [some draft of the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf): “A template defines a family of classes or functions. […] The declaration in a template-declaration shall […] declare […] a member class […].” This makes the member class a template in my book, as you have the `template` keyword above its declaration. And as I said, the compiler treats it as a template as well.

Comment: @MvG: You're wrong. `Texture` is a *member* of `Model` class template. `Texture` itself is not a template. If it was a template, then you would be able to write `Texture<int> t;` but you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace detail {
class Texture
{

};
}

template<class T>
class Model
{
    typedef detail::Texture Texture;
};
```

The `detail` namespace would discourage users of your API from accessing that class directly. If you don't export any API, you don't have to worry about this. The typedef allows access to the non-templated class through a name qualified with the templated one.

Comment: What if `Texture` wants to make use of `T` (which is a template argument to `Model` class template)? See my example.

Comment: @Nawaz: *If* the texture has to use `T`, *then* it must be templated in some form. In that case, your solution is the appropriate. But as I understood the OP, in particular his phrase “the texture object is the same”, this is not the case for him. So both approaches are valid, each for a given use case. One should choose the appropriate one, based on whether `Texture` needs `T` or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a common non-templated ancestor for this:

```
class ModelBase
{
    class Texture;
};


template<class T>
class Model : public ModelBase
{

};

class ModelBase::Texture
{

};
```

Comment: Hey, the question was actually just about the syntax involved in defining that non-template class, but this is a really great suggestion actually, because i had a map of pointers to these model objects, whose definition also depended on the template, which i didn't want. so i'm actually gonna take your suggestion and have them derive from a base class. +1 :P

Comment: @FatalCatharsis, if this is the answer you'll actually be using, it might be best to accept this. I hope Nawaz won't be angry, as his answer is currently the accepted one. Sorry there.

Comment: @MvG: What if `Texture` wants to make use of `T` (which is a template argument to `Model` class template)? See my example.

Comment: See my reply to that same comment on my other answer.

Comment: @MvG: it wasn't exactly an answer to the original question though, it was more of a tip for more elegant code. I do however, appreciate this tip, because it also solves another problem of mine. Sometimes i wish i could accept multiple solutions -_-.